# Is there an analog to `CalledProcessError` in the `asyncio` module?

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, subprocess, python-asyncio

Is there an analog, in the `asyncio` module, to the [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) exception from the `subprocess` module?

I would have expected there to be an analog, because the `asyncio` module creates the [`TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouterror) exception to replace the [`TimeoutExpired`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.TimeoutExpired) exception from the `subprocess` module. But there does not seem to be one.

As a sub-question: Does the `CalledProcessError` exception only work with instances of the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) class? Or does it also work with other classes (e.g. [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#process) from `asyncio` or [`Subprocess`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess) from `tornado.process`) which implement (child) process functionality?

It seems to be the case that the `CalledProcessError` exception might work with instances of classes similar, but distinct to `Popen`. For example, one can find on GitHub [examples](https://github.com/jupyterhub/batchspawner/blob/master/batchspawner/batchspawner.py#L197) of people calling `CalledProcessError` with an instance of the `Subprocess` class from `tornado.process`.

Note that in the above example, while it is true that `tornado.process` does have an alias for `subprocess.CalledProcessError`, based on the `import` statements at the top of the file that is *not* the exception being called; it is really `subprocess.CalledProcessError` being called.

If `CalledProcessError` also works with instances of the `Process` class from `asyncio`, then why doesn't `TimeoutExpired` also work with instances of the `Process` class from `asyncio`? In other words, in `asyncio` why was it necessary to create a new version (`TimeoutError`) of the `TimeoutExpired` exception, but *not* necessary to create a new version of the `CalledProcessError` exception?

At the end of the day [the source code for `CalledProcessError`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L60) isn't that complicated, so if I wanted to create a duplicate version for instances of the `Process` class from `asyncio`, I suppose I probably could, but it would seem desirable to first try avoid such code duplication.

**Note:** My current working mental model is that the "`asyncio.subprocess` module aims to do everything that the `subprocess` module does but asynchronously". To the extent that this mental model is incorrect, this question will likely contain inherent preconceptions/misconceptions.

Comment: `asyncio` is not intended to be a `subprocess` substitute. Your basic premise is wrong.

Comment: @user2357112: but there *is* [`subprocess`-like support in the `asyncio` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html), which is what I think the OP is referring to. I think the OP meant that that support is supposed to be the co-routine awaitable equivalent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it sounds like what you are saying is more correct than what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio` does not contain any equivalent for `CalledProcessError`, because it does not contain any equivalent for the things that raise `CalledProcessError`. There is no equivalent for `check_call`, `check_output`, `check_returncode`, or the `check` argument to `run`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such exception, no. The [`asyncio.subprocess` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) should be seen as the equivalent of [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). From [`asyncio.subprocess.Process` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process):

> The API of the `Process` class was designed to be close to the API of the `subprocess.Popen` class[.]

The `CalledProcessError` exception is only thrown by the higher-level functions in the same module (such as [`suprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)), each of which drives `Popen()` under the hood.

Just raise your own exception when the [`Process.returncode` value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process.returncode) is non-zero. You can re-use `CalledProcessError` for this if you want to, all it is is a container for the command run, return code, and the `stderr` and `stdout` strings. These are all built-in Python types, nothing `subprocess` specific.

Comment: I would upvote if I had sufficient reputation. This and the other answer are both very helpful; for this answer I like the last part clarifying how to write one's exception for this case.